# How can I do Flash 3d animation, Flash only supports 2d animation?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, animation, air, 3d

I am a beginner Flash developer. I saw some site like **[http://www.3dfreeair.com]**[1](http://www.3dfreeair.com) and another site also. On this site some 3d Flash animation there. How can I do like those animations? Because Flash only supports 2d animation. If you know, send me any reference url for studying 3d animation in Flash only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flash CS4 only supports very basic 3D animations and movement. If you want more advanced 3D in flash you need to use one of the various non Adobe 3D libraries.  The list includes:

- http://blog.papervision3d.org/
- http://away3d.com/
- http://www.flashsandy.org/
- http://blog.alternativaplatform.com/en/
- http://www.yogurt3d.com/en/
- http://www.ambiera.com/coppercube/index.html

Be aware that no 3D libraries in flash are hardware accelerated so you'll never get the same performance or features that you get with proper 3D graphics programs. If you do need high end hardware accelerated 3D graphics in the browser you may want to take a look at unity3D

- http://unity3d.com/

J

Answer (score 2):

Flash CS4 / Flash Player 10 supports basic 3d Animation of flat planes. Check [this](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/3d_animation.html) out. A quick search gave me lot of flash 3d tutorials.

Comment: Thanks Ravi.... Accept any of the answers to remove it from "unanswered" list ;-)

Answer (score 1):

[PaperVision3D](http://code.google.com/p/papervision3d/) is the most widely-used library and is excellent.

Comment: What is mean papervision3d? plz refer any url

Answer (score 0):

BTW,

Papervision3D is [evolving to PapervisionX](http://blog.papervision3d.org/2009/03/16/papervisionx-what-it-is-and-what-it-isnt/), and Alternativa3D 5.5 is [evolving to version 7](http://blog.alternativaplatform.com/en/2009/02/21/alternativa3d-7-in-progress/), both with specific support for player 10's anisotropic texture mapping capabilities, which should improve scene complexity and frame-rates considerably.

Also worth a peek is [ND3D](http://code.google.com/p/nd3d/) and Glen Rhode's [Flash Ray Engine](http://www.glenrhodes.com/wolf/myRay.html)

Comment: i like your answer :) Scott Evernden